# Repeat a matching pattern that may not exist

Tags: javascript, regex

We have this simple regular expression:

```
var regex = \a[bc]*\;

// matches 'ab', 'abb', 'accc'
```

but this regex also matches 'aa'.
In other words, because the pattern [bc] did not exist, it repeated the 'a'. But the intent was to catch the 'a' then any number of 'b' or 'c'.

How would you apply the * (repeat pattern) so it only acts on the previous character if it matched anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `*` is not applied to `a` in the [`regex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). `*` is applied to only *character class* `[bc]`.

You haven't matched the complete string. You have to use `^`(starts with) and `$`(ends with) in your `regex`.

```
var regex = /^a[bc]*$/;
//           ^      ^
```

OR use *word boundary* selector, if you want to match substring in a larger string.

```
var regex = /\ba[bc]*\b/;
//           ^^      ^^
```

Demo:

```js
var regex = /\ba[bc]*\b/;

document.write("regex.test('a'): " + regex.test('a')); // true
document.write("<br />regex.test('abc'): " + regex.test('abc')); // true
document.write("<br />regex.test('abcab'): " + regex.test('abcab')); // false
document.write("<br />regex.test('aa'): " + regex.test('aa')); // false


// Words in string
document.write("<br /><br />regex.test('this is a adbc'): " + regex.test('this is a adbc')); // true 'a'
document.write("<br />regex.test('this is adbc'): " + regex.test('this is adbc')); // false
```

**Visual Representation**

[image]

Comment: What if the pattern is mid-string: 'junk aa junk' should not match. but 'junk ab junk' should match 'ab' and 'junk ac junk' should match 'ac'